# Ticker messages in menu bar

Tags: c#, menubar

I have a win forms application, and the user wants to have a scrolling message (like the news ticker feed).

I am okay with the ticker itself - the customer wants the information to scroll in the unused area of the menu bar - along the top of the main window.

I am not sure if you can stack a control on top of the menu bar or not.

Does anyone know if this can be accomplished (stacking on the menu bar), if you do - please provide some direction.   c# please

thank you

Comment: How about putting the Menü Bar into a Panel, Not the Form directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the class that i used....

it will create a custom control in the toolbox...   drag it onto the control you want, and walla

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Winform_menu
{
  internal class NewsTicker : Panel
  {
     private Timer mScroller; // Scroll timer
     private int mOffset; // Offset of scrolled text
   private string mText; // Text to scroll
private Size mPixels; // Width of text in pixels
private Bitmap mBuffer; // Double-buffering buffer

public NewsTicker()
{
  mScroller = new Timer();
  mScroller.Interval = 30;
  mScroller.Enabled = false;
  mScroller.Tick += DoScroll;
}

[Browsable(true)]
public override string Text
{
  get { return mText; }
  set
  {
    mText = value;
    mScroller.Enabled = mText.Length > 0;
    mPixels = TextRenderer.MeasureText(mText, this.Font);
    mOffset = this.Width;
  }
}

private void DoScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Adjust offset and paint
  mOffset -= 1;
  if (mOffset < -mPixels.Width) mOffset = this.Width;
  Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  // Do nothing
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  if (mBuffer == null || mBuffer.Width != this.Width || mBuffer.Height != this.Height)
    mBuffer = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
  Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(mBuffer);
  Brush bbr = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
  Brush fbr = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
  gr.FillRectangle(bbr, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
  gr.DrawString(mText, this.Font, fbr, mOffset, 0);
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(mBuffer, 0, 0);
  bbr.Dispose();
  fbr.Dispose();
  gr.Dispose();
     }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Odd request.  Here is something to get you started:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  menuStrip1.Paint += menuStrip1_Paint;
}

void menuStrip1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  int startLeft = 0;
  foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menu in menuStrip1.Items) {
    startLeft = Math.Max(startLeft, menu.Bounds.Right);
  }
  startLeft += 16;
  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red,
                           new Rectangle(startLeft, 0, 
                                         menuStrip1.ClientSize.Width - startLeft - 1,
                                         menuStrip1.ClientSize.Height - 1));
}
```

It finds the part of the menu strip that is available.  That's the rectangle you would draw into using a timer.  Will probably flicker.

Comment: nice - thank you....   but the flicker was too much for them   +1 for helping me in the right direction